# Duplicate GLX FBConfigs from glXChooseFBConfig

Tags: opengl, x11

When running `glxinfo`, or using my own code (calling `glXChooseFBConfig` to get a list of GLX framebuffer configurations), I see that there are entries which are identical except for their ID code.

For example:

```
$ glxinfo
...
0x77  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
...
0xae  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
...
```

What is the reason for this duplication? Is there an underlying difference between these seemingly identical modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though they have the same buffer configuration from the point of view of OpenGL, they differ from the point of view of X11. Specifically, they have different X Visual bit-depths (one is a 24-bit X visual and one is a 32-bit X visual)

[note: I found this out while I was composing the question, but since I hadn't found an answer in my web searches I'm posting the question and answer here anyway -- maybe someone else will find it useful in the future.]